How to prevent RocksDB from growing?
I'm running a local devnet node and try to prevent RocksDB from growing indefinitely. It currently occupies around 750gb. Which configuration parameter do I need to set to limit db size? This is how I run it now:
target/release/solana-validator 
--enable-rpc-transaction-history 
--enable-extended-tx-metadata-storage
--limit-ledger-size 50000000 
--log /home/user/solana/solana.log 
--log-messages-bytes-limit 4096 
--require-tower 
--ledger /home/user/solana/net/../config/bootstrap-validator 
--rpc-port 8899 
--snapshot-interval-slots 200 
--no-incremental-snapshots 
--identity /home/user/solana/net/../config/bootstrap-validator/identity.json 
--vote-account /home/user/solana/net/../config/bootstrap-validator/vote-account.json 
--rpc-faucet-address '127.0.0.1:9900' 
--no-poh-speed-test 
--no-os-network-limits-test 
--no-wait-for-vote-to-start-leader 
--full-rpc-api 
--allow-private-addr 
--gossip-port 8001`

Thank you!

The --limit-ledger-size parameter is the one that controls the size of rocksdb. This is a bit strange, since 50M shreds should take up ~100GB according to the code at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/aa72aa87790277619d12c27f1ebc864d23739557/core/src/ledger_cleanup_service.rs#L26-L37
Given that you're also passing --enable-extended-tx-metadata-storage, those 50M shreds may end up taking more space. Either way, I'd recommend reducing the number passed to --limit-ledger-size.
More information at https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/guides/validator-start#limiting-ledger-size-to-conserve-disk-space

The problem is that --limit-ledger-size is at the minimum value already. Validator won't start if it is set below 50M

Ah darn, I'm not sure what else to suggest, sorry!
